# Azure Authentication - Access Token returning wrong AUD(00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000)

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to authenticate with API Management in Azure through OAuth. I've set up that piece fine.
However from the response, the aud(00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000) is invalid from the access token.
Any suggestions/ideas to get the accurate aud in access_token.

Comment: Installed the AAD Microsoft Authentication Library from the react application.                               const config = {
  auth: {
    authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common',
    clientId: '<Client ID>',
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/callback'
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: "localStorage",
    storeAuthStateInCookie: true
  }
};

Comment: No, I havent passed any scope parameter. If needed so, where do I need to add/pass it.

Comment: Passed clientId, authority and redirect_uri. PLease do the needful.

Comment: You need to pass a scope. Define one in "Expose an API" and then use that when authenticating.

Comment: Created a scope, however I am not sure where to pass the particular scope from my react app using MSAL

Comment: You can pass it to e.g. loginPopup/loginRedirect.

Answer (score 4):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

I generated the access token with the same **`aud`** as you and got the validation error:

[image]

[image]

I agree with *juunas*, To authenticate with API Management in Azure through OAuth, make sure to pass the **scope** while generating the access token.

I created an Azure AD Application, **exposed an API and added scope** like below:

[image]

Added API permissions like below:

[image]

To resolve the error, make sure to pass **scope** as `api://AppID/.default`.

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:api://ee1782a6-a994-4013-a396-XXXXX/.default
grant_type:client_credentials
```

A valid access token to access APIM will be generated like below:

[image]

> To pass the particular scope from react app using MSAL you can make refer the below sample code:

```js
auth: { 
authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common",
clientId: "ClientID",
postLogoutRedirectUri: RedirectURI
redirectUri: RedirectURI
validateAuthority: true,
navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true,
},
cache:
{ cacheLocation: 'sessionStorage',
storeAuthStateInCookie: true,
},
},
{
scopes: ['api://clientid/.default']
},
LoginType.Redirect
```

**References:**

[OAuth 2.0 Authorisation with the Client Credentials Flow on Azure API Management by **Paco de la Cruz**](https://engineering.deloitte.com.au/articles/oauth2-client-credentials-flow-on-azure-api-management)

[Connect React App with Azure AD using react msal by **Ray**](https://medium.com/@pavelray/connect-your-react-app-with-azure-ad-using-3ddd39223d27)

Comment: I see this problem when using Vue 3 https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/msal-browser-samples/vue3-sample-app sample instead of React and I have solved like in the other answer wiht an id token instead of an access token

Answer (score 2):

You have mistaken the values.

**TL;DR: ignore "access token", obtain and read "id token" and verify that "aud" field is your client ID.**

First you might obtain a single-use access code (likely something like 0.ABC). Optionally you could fetch open id token. "scope" must include "openid"

Then you can fetch actual open id token using the single-use code. "scope" must be "openid" again. Response might include:

- access token - which can be anything including random number of characters, string, your full details or an JWT; I believe that Microsoft returns JWT which is meant to the "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000" audience (meaning "only 00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000 can use it - ignore if you are NOT the one")
- id token - which is an JWT and should contain your application ID (client ID) in the "aud" field

Always check the "aud" as this says who is the token created for. If it is not you - the token is not for you.

Comment: See my comment here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76886257/how-to-validate-access-token-from-azuread-in-python#comment137396672_77918893 for a practical implementation with code (notice that I have changed 2 lines of the linked answer)

Comment: Confused. Blazor WASM SPA authenticating and wanting to call downstream Web API. In the `id_token` aud is equal to my SPA app id. The `access_token` however, still has Graph as aud and not my own Web API.

Comment: @baouss Correct, you need the access_token to call Graph. But that's different from auth/authz for your own api, there you should use the id_token.