# How to validate access token from AzureAD in python?

Tags: python, jwt, single-sign-on, fastapi, azure-ad-msal

What is the recommended way to validate the access token in backend? Any library that handles it?

Another team has implemented the frontend they send the access token in the Bearer attributed in the header.

I found https://github.com/odwyersoftware/azure-ad-verify-token but it has only 17 Stars. I thought microsoft should have support for it in MSAL (https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python) but seems not.

Any suggestions on how to implement it in a secure way? Or any good libs that handles the validation.

I have tried write the code my self but I get problems but worried its not secured and the code got messy. Also tried above lib but should like to have some more popular so its not a security risk.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Microsoft does not have a Python library to validate access tokens. Nevertheless, I found [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-webapi-azurefunctions/blob/master/Function/secureFlaskApp/__init__.py) official sample.

You can check the requires_auth() function, which is used to validate the access token.

Comment: Notice an open issue asking to better define the usage with a **scope**, and my comment there https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-webapi-azurefunctions/issues/4#issuecomment-1925736220

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using the `PyJWT` and `cryptography` libraries

Note: Please adjust `issuer_url` and `audience` to match your AzureAD setup.

```
import jwt
import base64
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.rsa import RSAPublicNumbers
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen

def token_is_valid(tenant_id, client_id, token):
    jwks_url = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/discovery/v2.0/keys"
    issuer_url = f"https://sts.windows.net/{tenant_id}/"
    audience = f"api://{client_id}"

    jwks = json.loads(urlopen(jwks_url).read())
    unverified_header = jwt.get_unverified_header(token)
    rsa_key = find_rsa_key(jwks, unverified_header)
    public_key = rsa_pem_from_jwk(rsa_key)

    return jwt.decode(
      token,
      public_key,
      verify=True,
      algorithms=["RS256"],
      audience=audience,
      issuer=issuer_url
    )

def find_rsa_key(jwks, unverified_header):
    for key in jwks["keys"]:
        if key["kid"] == unverified_header["kid"]:
            return {
              "kty": key["kty"],
              "kid": key["kid"],
              "use": key["use"],
              "n": key["n"],
              "e": key["e"]
            }

def ensure_bytes(key):
    if isinstance(key, str):
        key = key.encode('utf-8')
    return key


def decode_value(val):
    decoded = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(ensure_bytes(val) + b'==')
    return int.from_bytes(decoded, 'big')


def rsa_pem_from_jwk(jwk):
    return RSAPublicNumbers(
        n=decode_value(jwk['n']),
        e=decode_value(jwk['e'])
    ).public_key(default_backend()).public_bytes(
        encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
        format=serialization.PublicFormat.SubjectPublicKeyInfo
    )
```

This is based on Roberts blog post:

https://robertoprevato.github.io/Validating-JWT-Bearer-tokens-from-Azure-AD-in-Python/

References:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tokens-overview

Comment: With these 2 lines it works with an id token instead of an access token `     issuer_url = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/v2.0"
    audience = f"{client_id}"`. If I produce the access token with https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/msal-browser-samples/vue3-sample-app I see this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74886417/azure-authentication-access-token-returning-wrong-aud00000003-0000-0000-c000

Comment: I have also tested that, if I define app roles in app registration and assign them to users/groups via  Enterprise apps blade, I can find the scopes/claims in the roles of the JWT token, validated - as per my comment above - from the **id** token, **not** the access token. Hence, afaics, the id tokens work for both authentication and authorization in the web api.

Comment: @Giulio Interesting, I've updated my answer to reflect you experience, I kept trying different values for `issuer_url` and `audience` until something worked on my end.

Answer (score 0):

Code from @Justin Tanner implemented as class, and just updating public keys if expired.

```
   import time
import jwt
import base64
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.rsa import RSAPublicNumbers
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen


class OAuth2TokenValidation:

    def __init__(self, tenant_id, client_id):
        self.jwks_url = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/discovery/v2.0/keys"
        self.issuer_url = f"https://sts.windows.net/{tenant_id}/"
        self.audience = f"api://{client_id}"

        self.jwks = json.loads(urlopen(self.jwks_url).read())
        self.last_jwks_public_key_update = time.time()

    def validate_token_and_decode_it(self, token):
        """
        :param token: the jwt token to validate
        :return: the decoded token if valid, else raises an exception
        """

        try:
            unverified_header = jwt.get_unverified_header(token)
        except Exception as e:
            raise Exception(f"Unable to decode authorization token headers: {e}")

        try:
            rsa_key = OAuth2TokenValidation.find_rsa_key(self.jwks, unverified_header)
            public_key = OAuth2TokenValidation.rsa_pem_from_jwk(rsa_key)

            return jwt.decode(
              token,
              public_key,
              verify=True,
              algorithms=["RS256"],
              audience=self.audience,
              issuer=self.issuer_url
            )

        except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
            raise Exception("Token has expired")
        except jwt.InvalidTokenError:
            raise Exception("Invalid token")
        except Exception as e:
            # update the public key if not fresh and try again
            if int(time.time() - self.last_jwks_public_key_update) > 60:
                self.jwks = json.loads(urlopen(self.jwks_url).read())
                self.last_jwks_public_key_update = time.time()
                return self.validate_token_and_decode_it(token)
            else:
                print(f"Error validating token: {e}")

    @staticmethod
    def find_rsa_key(jwks, unverified_header):
        for key in jwks["keys"]:
            if key["kid"] == unverified_header["kid"]:
                return {
                  "kty": key["kty"],
                  "kid": key["kid"],
                  "use": key["use"],
                  "n": key["n"],
                  "e": key["e"]
                }

    @staticmethod
    def ensure_bytes(key):
        if isinstance(key, str):
            key = key.encode('utf-8')
        return key

    @staticmethod
    def decode_value(val):
        decoded = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(OAuth2TokenValidation.ensure_bytes(val) + b'==')
        return int.from_bytes(decoded, 'big')

    @staticmethod
    def rsa_pem_from_jwk(jwk):
        return RSAPublicNumbers(
            n=OAuth2TokenValidation.decode_value(jwk['n']),
            e=OAuth2TokenValidation.decode_value(jwk['e'])
        ).public_key(default_backend()).public_bytes(
            encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
            format=serialization.PublicFormat.SubjectPublicKeyInfo
        )
```